# Writing my own wrapper class and declaring array of its elements

Tags: java, arrays, class, char, declaration

I wrote simple class TheChar, which is wrapper class for primitive type char.

```
public class TheChar {
    private char value;
    public TheChar(char value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public char getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Why can't I declare an array of TheChars like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TheChar[] lol =  {'o','a'};
    }
}
```

Because when I use Character class the declaration

```
Character[] lol = {'o','a'};
```

will fork fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must wrap the `chars` first, as in:

`TheChar[] lol =  {new TheChar('o'), new TheChar('a')};`

Because `'a'` is a `char`, and can't be casted to a custom class

Comment: But when I use Character class, I can just type `Character[] lol = {'o', 'a'};`

Comment: `Character` class is part of the Java language, so it has inner mechanisms to do the casting. It simply makes easier for you so you don't need to call the constructor every time. When you do `String s="foo"`, you should write `String s=new String("foo")`, but it has been implemented for you.

Answer (score 2):

`Character` is not simple wrapper for primitive `char`, conversion between them is support by java compiler. To be able to define your array in way like you want, you need to write not only wrapper but java compiler as well.